# What does a double backtick/grave (``) mean in c++ documentation?

Tags: c++, syntax, documentation, backquote

I am learning c++ and am reading [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) from c-faq.com. Frequently, when referring to an unknown  element, the author will preface the name of the element with ``.

What does that mean? I'm vaguely familiar with * or & before a variable or function but not ``.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are double quotes:

```
``Start of quote. Quote end''
```

It is a format for TeX, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52354).